# Reaching a Docker environment running in VMware from LAN

Tags: networking, 20.04, vmware, docker

Here is my setup:

I have a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine running in VMware (vSphere client).

On this machine, I have a local Drupal website running in Docker using Wodby Docker4Drupal https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal

The website can be accessed on the Ubuntu machine on http://drupal.localhost:8000.

The Ubuntu machine has an IP of **192.168.10.100** which I can ping from my local Windows machine which is on the same LAN (Windows computer IP address is 192.168.10.97).

Is there any way that I could access the Drupal website directly from the browser on a computer that is on the same LAN (ie. my Windows machine)?

I have tried to access http://192.168.10.100:8000 but I get a `404 page not found` message. On port `80` I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Any idea?

I shall also mention that on the Ubuntu VM, I also get *the same* `404 page not found` if I try to reach http://0.0.0.0:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000. Only the hostname configured within the project resolves to the Drupal website (http://drupal.localhost:8000).

---

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` I am using.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - d4d-db-data:/var/lib/mysql # Use bind mount

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached

  crond:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_crond"
    environment:
      CRONTAB: "0 * * * * drush -r /var/www/html/web cron"
    command: sudo -E LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so crond -f -d 0
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    #      NGINX_DRUPAL_FILE_PROXY_URL: http://example.com
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.rule=Host(`mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
    - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  d4d-db-data:
```

Comment: You get a 404 not found error because something (traefik, or nginx, not sure) expects the HTTP `Host` header to have that `drupal.localhost` value (which is not the case when you go to `http://192.168.10.100:8000` or `http://localhost:8000`)

Comment: This makes quite a lot of sense... I don't really know how I could change that behavior but it might be related to what you said so I'll look into that direction. Earlier I thought about a Drupal internal which is called `trusted_host_settings` but it's not enabled so this is ruled out.

Comment: Does the error message look like it's from nginx?

Comment: I really don't know how I could answer that? It's just plain text, no styling, that's all I can say. That said, I got it fixed now and you were right, it had to do with the host name on Traefik. In nginx `labels` I had to add another http routers rule with the local IP address as the host name and it worked straight away! I can now reach my website on http://192.168.10.100:8000 - thanks for your advice!

Comment: Well, it could look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POejV.png. In any case, since you have solved it, you can post what you did as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I surely will post my answer and no, it didn't look like that ;) Full text `404 page not found` like here https://i.imgur.com/Cg0nGb4.png

Comment: Ah, that's how Traefik responds (test with a barebones `traefik:latest` container and you get pretty much the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was only a setting in Traefik. I had to add a second router http rule for the nginx container in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx_lan.rule=Host(`192.168.10.100`)"
```

So the full nginx section now looks like that:

```
  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    #      NGINX_DRUPAL_FILE_PROXY_URL: http://example.com
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx_lan.rule=Host(`192.168.10.100`)"
```

It works fine. I can now access my Drupal website at http://192.168.10.100:8000 from any other device on the same LAN.

In my case, `PROJECT_BASE_URL` and `PROJECT_NAME` are configured in an `.env` file and correspond to `drupal.localhost` and `drupal` respectively.

Thanks @muru for the help!